# POST NameValueCollection to Web API using WebClient.UploadValues for .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-web-api

I have created a Web API that serves up PDF documents. I have a 4.5/4.0 client, a Javascript-only client, and I'm now attempting to create a .NET 3.5 client for a few older websites that we have. I understand that I could NUGET a few of the libraries, but from my understanding... HttpClient only works in 4.0 right now?

In any case, I'd like to use WebClient as a means to getting this done. Currently I have:

```
Dim js As New Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
Dim client As New Net.WebClient
client.Headers(Net.HttpRequestHeader.ContentType) = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Dim serializedData As String = js.Serialize(Me.PDFReport)
Dim collection As New NameValueCollection
collection.Add("value", serializedData)
Dim response As Byte() = client.UploadValues("http://www.mywebsite.com/api/report/Post/", collection)
```

I'm shoving my serialized data into a NameValueCollection so that I can return a Byte array with the PDF in it. I can't seem to get it to show up on the Web API side:

```
Public Function Post(str As NameValueCollection) As Byte()
    Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim obj As PDFReport = js.Deserialize(Of PDFReport)(str("value"))
    Dim rpt As New ReportService(obj)
    'Return Nothing (Commented for now until I figure out how to get values)
End Function
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to get the values over the wire unless I use UploadString, but then I can't grab a response that is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

try modifying your action parameter to be `FormDataCollection` and see if it works. And also have this kind of check (change it to VB) to catch any model state errors.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
  throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, this.ModelState));
}
```

Comment: FormDataCollection is namespaced in System.Net.Http.Formatting. I was hoping to refrain from using it in .NET 3.5. From some of the reading I've done, I may be able to simply import the HttpClient dlls into my .NET 3.5 project in order to take advantage of the client and HttpResponseMessage. If I can do that, there is no need for this.